# Are there good sites about working with big data?

Tags: data-mining, bigdata

I am looking sites\blogs where people explain how they solving perfomance and other problems with big data. I know some resources about scalable web applications and sites(like twitter, facebook). it's ok but i am looking concrete algorithms mainly for data mining.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a lot of the things done on big data do no qualify as "data mining".
At most they *apply* previously learned rules to uniform big data, mostly in predicting consumer interest to serve them ads. But that mostly boils down to "has interest in sports" type of decisions. Quite a huge error rate is acceptable here, as there is next to no cost to serving someone a sports ad who is not interested in sports. The web is full of stories where Google put people into the wrong consumer segments. Often even predicting the gender incorrectly.

Whenever you see "big data", take that with a big grain of salt. It mostly is bragging and buzzword bingo. The challenge with big data still lies in actually getting it done, not (yet) with getting it done right.

A good example is this article: http://www.technologyreview.com/web/39487/

Yahoo predicted (using Twitter "big data" and pushing this article that claims they are much better than exit polls etc. brag brag brag) that "romney has a 90% chance of winning south carolina". In reality, Romney got 28%, while Gingrich got 40%.

Or try out some of the "sentiment analysis" type of tools. They will tell you that a twitter post containing "puppies" is positive, and containing "cockroaches" is negative. And that is about the quality they get with "sentiment analysis" these days. Again, they are so much focused on just getting *anything* out of the data, they are not yet at the point of actually analyzing (or even *validating*) the results. Sorry. I bet I'll get some downvotes for being this critical, but this is what is happening everyday. See the yahoo example. They apparently were able to process their "big data", but their results surely aren't ready for prime time, they still need to work on that.

And again, for some situations such as ad targeting, error rates can be quite high. Anything better than random, is, well, better than random! Which means more money than if you would just serve random ads. So it isn't worthless; just maybe not comparable to non-big-data approaches.